# Is Inkscape unable to import asymptote vector graphics properly?

Tags: vector, inkscape

## Background:

***Inkscape*** usually imports vectors properly, with no issues, both from EPS or PDF. What helps in this process is "Poppler".

*Asymptote* is a  software that given some data is able to render 3d graphics, also is able to export them to EPS or PDF.

## Question:

The files obtained using Asymptote can't be opened as vectors with Inkscape (the are opened as bitmap images). Why?

Am I suppose to do something additional in order to open the files with ***Inkscape***?

***P.S.:*** Asymptote output example: [test.eps](http://goo.gl/freBPM), [test.pdf](http://goo.gl/eKxV4Y).

Comment: For me it imports vector in v0.91 (tested the pdf) but it seems there are features missing in inkscape to properly handle the import (maybe gradient meshes). I see segments of the ball of solid color similar to a wire mesh.

Comment: @Chris I don't get it, I also have v0.91, would you give me a detailed step by step on how you imported it?, thanks.

Comment: I downloaded the pdf and opened it in Inkscape. I left the “import via poppler” option unchecked and that's it. By the “Precision of ...” parameter you can decide about the number of polygons to approximate the underlying gradient mesh I guess. With this parameter set to 20 and adding a blur of 2 % to the whole ball gives a pretty good result (may have to be clipped afterwards).

Comment: @Chris All right, not exactly what I'd like, but I think it works by now ( I'd love to import it using the finest precision, but it seems like my computer is unable to do it.); I'm still looking for a way to get a HQ image from these files.